# Passing object properties to function call in Ruby class

Tags: ruby, class

```
def printer_outside_class(value)
 puts value
end

class Prints
 attr_accessor :value
 def initialize(a)
   @value = a
 end
 printer_outside_class(@value)
end 

Prints.new(100)
```

I do not get any output instead it throws a warning "instance variable @value not initialized". Ruby executes the class line by line so before the `initialize` function gets called, `printer_outside_class(value)` gets called.

Is it possible to somehow pass the variable `value` to the outer `printer_outside_class(@value)` function call? 
`value` should be passed from outside and it need not be via constructor.

Note:  I am free to change the constructor, add arbitrary code to `Prints` class, add a new class and have the liberty to call `Prints` class however I want. However, I won't be able to move the function call `printer_outside_class(@value)` inside a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understood the question, the way to go would be to use instance variable on class level:

```
def printer_outside_class(value)
  puts value
end

class Prints
  @value = 100
  def self.value; @value; end
  def self.value=(neu); @value = neu; end

  def initialize(a)
     self.class.value = a
     printer_outside_class(a)
   end
  printer_outside_class(value)
end

Prints.new(123)
```

Comment: I like how you used `neu` for _new_ value. :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question to add more clarification. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What your updated version of the question has in common with my answer? I use _instance variable on class level_. You use _plain instance variable_. They are completely different things and I believe you should understand how class scoping is works in ruby and what’s being executed immediately on parsing and what’s deferred till real method calls.